# how create a new generic type and redefine == in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the next haskell code successfully working:

```
type Relation a = [[a]]

isAEquivalentRelation   ::  Eq a  => Relation a -> Bool
isAEquivalentRelation x   =   isASimetricRelation x && isAReflexiveRelation x && isATransitiveRelation x

isASimetricRelation   ::  Eq a  =>  Relation a -> Bool
isASimetricRelation []   =   True
isASimetricRelation (x:xs)   =   (elem (reverse x) (x:xs)) && (isASimetricRelation  (filter (/= y) xs)) where y = (reverse x)

isAReflexiveRelation   ::  Eq a  =>  Relation a -> Bool 
isAReflexiveRelation []   =   True
isAReflexiveRelation x   =   isAReflexiveRelationRec (filter (\ a -> a !! 0 == a !! 1) x) x

isAReflexiveRelationRec   ::   Eq a   =>  Relation a -> Relation a -> Bool 
isAReflexiveRelationRec [] _  =   False
isAReflexiveRelationRec _ []  =   True
isAReflexiveRelationRec pr (x:xs)  = or ( map (== [x!!0,x!!0]) pr) && or ( map (== [x!!1,x!!1]) pr) && isAReflexiveRelationRec pr xs

isATransitiveRelation   ::   Eq a   =>  Relation a -> Bool 
isATransitiveRelation []   =   True
isATransitiveRelation x   =   isATransitiveRelationRec x x

isATransitiveRelationRec   ::   Eq a   => Relation a -> Relation a -> Bool 
isATransitiveRelationRec _ []   =   True
isATransitiveRelationRec original (x:xs)   =   and ( map (\ a -> elem a original) (map (\ a -> [x !! 0, a !! 1]) (filter (\ a -> x !! 1 == a !! 0) original)) ) && isATransitiveRelationRec original xs

areEqual   ::   Eq a  =>  Relation a -> Relation a -> Bool
areEqual x y  =   subset x y && subset y x 

subset   ::   Eq a  =>  Relation a -> Relation a -> Bool
subset [] _ = True
subset _ [] = False
subset x y = and (map (\ a -> elem a y) x)
```

The issue is that I need to redefine the == of the Relation type using the areEqual method that I have implemented but i can't achieve this working. I've tried a lot of things with classes and instances and datas but I'm stucked, how can i declare a generic Relation type and redefine the operator == to match areEqual method ?

Comment: If you want `Relation` to have its own instances, it should be a fresh type (not a type synonym). One way of doing that is `newtype Relation a = Relation [[a]]` (note that doing this means you'll have to wrap and unwrap `Relation` all over the place). Then, you can define `==` for `Relation` with `instance Eq a => Eq Relation where { (==) = areEqual }`.

Comment: Since you appear to really be encoding binary relations, I would make that explicit with `[(a,a)]` instead of `[[a]]`.

Comment: Also, note that the properties you are testing must hold for *all* values of type `a`, not just the ones you see in the `Relation`. For example, `[[0,0]] :: [[Int]]` would not be a reflexive relation on `Int`,  because `[1,1] :: [Int]` (among others) is not present.

Comment: Minor note: the word is spelled "symmetric". And the ultimate thing you're after is an "equivalence" relation.

Comment: Typically, the `...Rec` functions you've defined would be defined locally, in `where` clauses. Generally speaking, a top-level function should be one with a clear meaning of its own, and should have a comment documenting that meaning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry about my english, i'm from Cuba, I did what @Alec said and after a lot of try and lecture finish I could achieve what i was expecting. :) really nice